# PHPUnit test in Zend Framework 3

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, zend-framework3, phpunit

I am trying to create a test case on the login action with 2 post parameter the code is as here

```
    namespace UserTest\Controller;

use Application\Controller\LoginController;
use Application\Service\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils; 
use Zend\Stdlib\Parameters;
use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;  

class UserControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase 
    public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
    {
        $p = new Parameters();
        $p->set('username','foo');
        $p->set('password','bar');
        $this->getRequest()->setMethod('POST');
        $this->getRequest()->setPost($p);
        $this->dispatch('widget/login');
        $this->assertModuleName('Application');
        $this->assertControllerName(LoginController::class);
        $this->assertControllerClass('LoginController');
        //$this->assertMatchedRouteName('login');
}
```

and executing the test case from the command line the command is

> ./vendor/bin/phpunit
>   /var/www/myproject/application/module/Application/test/Controller/UserControllerTest.php

and the script throwing error that is

Fatal error: Declaration of Application\Service\AuthenticationService::authenticate() must be compatible with Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService::authenticate(?Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface $adapter = NULL) in /var/www/myproject/application/module/Application/src/Application/Service/AuthenticationService.php on line 16

Please, help me to fix this issue and let me know what i am doing wrong in it

Comment: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/test-doubles.html#mock-objects

Comment: Have you set up your dependency injection? https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/unit-testing/#configuring-the-service-manager-for-the-tests

Comment: @user2087816 - I have followed your suggestion but a confusion  like why i need to include all the dependency injection as i have a main controller that include all the things i just need to check the method by pass respected parameter from the testController

If you check my above code  I am calling controller with Post parameter to test the method.